# get count controller args from router?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, dispatcher, router

ok im learning on how to make my own custom mvc system, so far i have created things like router and the controller.

example i have a controller profile class and an url www.helloworld.com/args1/args2/args3

```
class Profiles
{
    function index($args1,$args2)
    {
        echo var_dump($args1,$args2);
    }
}
```

heres are part of my router class that execute the method and the parms

```
        if (is_callable(array($controller,$method))) {
            call_user_func_array(array($controller, $method), $this->params);
        }
```

so far no error but somehow i need to give a 404. if the `$this->params` is different then the `count(params)` in the method that i call at `call_user_func_array(array($controller, $method), 
$this->params);`

ok what im thinking is if count get params not same as count params at the called class then 404,
lets say i can count my $this->params it gave me a 3. but how about the params in the called class ?
how can we **count params in a called class by call_user_func_array**?

Thanks for looking in

Adam Ramadhan

Comment: should probably be a 500 "internal sever error", a 404 is a "not found error"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I know, there is no way of getting the parameter count for a method without using [reflection](http://php.net/reflection). However, it's pretty simple and would look something like this:

```
$reflector = new ReflectionClass('Profiles');
$method = $reflector->getMethod('index');
$parameters = $method->getParameters();

printf('%s expects %d parameters', $method->name, count($parameters));
```

Will yield

```
index expects 2 parameter
```

Note that reflection always comes with a cost. However, the performance implications of this should not be noticable.

Comment: Note that this doesn't account for optional arguments. Also, why get all the ReflectionParameters if all we need is a count?

Comment: @abesto This is just for illustrating what he can do with reflection. Maybe he want to match the parameter names or something else.

Answer (score 1):

You could use reflection:

```
$refclass = new ReflectionClass($controller);
$param_count = $refclass->getMethod($method)->getNumberOfRequiredParameters();
if ($param_count <= count($this->params)) {
    $refclass->invokeArgs($controller, $this->params);
} else {
    // 404
}
```

Can be made stricter by checking if there are too many parameters.

Comment: getNumberOfRequiredParameters i haven't know that.

Answer (score 0):

> count params in a called class by call_user_func_array

Rather simple, actually. You can determine the amount of parameters by fetching them into an array using [func_get_args](http://php.net/func_get_args), and then [count](http://php.net/count) them. Example:

```
<?php
function foo( ) {
   echo "I have received " . count( func_get_args( ) ) . " parameters.";
}
foo( ); // I have received 0 parameters.
foo( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ); // I have received 5 parameters.
```

Comment: Ah, didn't get that it was about the expected number of parameters. In that case, my example is incorrect, sorry.